# How to render jsx/html that is inside variable (or prop)?

Tags: reactjs

```
const Footer = () => {
  let a="<b>Hey</b>"
  return (
    <div>
      Some bold text: {a}
    </div>
  )
}
```

This will only render as `Some bold text: <b>Hey</b>`. How to get the bold text rendered as bold? The variable content is my own, so I do not have to worry about eval stuff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to use [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/dangerously-set-inner-html.html)

```
const Footer = () => {
  let a= { __html: "<b>Hey</b>" };
  return (
    <div>
      Some bold text: <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={a} />
    </div>
  )
}
```