# JSX with a HTML tag from a variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React component defined in JSX which returns a cell using either `td` or `th`, e.g.:

```
if(myType === 'header') {
  return (
    <th {...myProps}>
      <div className="some-class">some content</div>
    </th>
  );
}

return (
  <td {...myProps}>
    <div className="some-class">some content</div>
  </td>
);
```

Would it be possible to write the JSX in such a way that the HTML tag is taken from a variable? Like:

```
let myTag = myType === "header" ? 'th' : 'td';
return (
  <{myTag} {...myProps}>
    <div className="some-class">some content</div>
  </{myTag}>
);
```

The above code returns an error:

> "unexpected token" pointing at `{`.

I am using Webpack with the Babel plugin to compile JSX.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try setting your component state and rendering like so:

```
render: function() {
    return(
        <this.state.tagName {...myProps}>
          <div className="some-class">some content</div>
        </this.state.tagName>
    );
},
```

Comment: Eh, thanks for the tip. It will work without worrying about the state, just assign the tag name to a variable and use it inside JSX, e.g.: `let tx = 'td'; return (<tx {...myProps}>...` and so on.

Comment: Actually, the variable name must start with a capital letter, otherwise react treats it as a HTML tag and renders `tx` instead of the value of the variable. If the variable name is `Tx` then it correctly renders its content (i.e. `td` or `th`).

Comment: well but how to do that without "this..." statement after the "<"?

Comment: This can be used like OP intended: `const Wrapper = (condition) ? 'th' : 'td';` Then use it like a normal component: `<Wrapper {} />`

Answer (score 6):

You can do something like:

```
const content = <div> some content </div>
return (
  {myType === 'header'
    ? <th>{content}</th>
    : <td>{content}</td>
  }
)
```

Note that this does not really solve your question about "dynamic tag" but rather the problem you seem to have.

Comment: Did you test this solution? Will it work without `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`? Will I not run into the problem described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36800148/how-to-render-jsx-html-that-is-inside-variable-or-prop and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23616226/insert-html-with-react-variable-statements-jsx ?

Comment: It's not doing the same thing. In your link they use strings with html tags in them. It's not what I am doing here.

Answer (score 3):

The first answer did not work for my case so I solved it in another way.
From [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html) each element converts to pure JS [like this](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?browsers=defaults%2C%20not%20ie%2011%2C%20not%20ie_mob%2011&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=GYVwdgxgLglg9mABACwKYBt1wBQEpEDeAUIogE6pQhlIA8AJjAG4B8AEhlogO5xnr0AhLQD0jVgG4iAXyJA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=react&prettier=true&targets=&version=7.12.12&externalPlugins=).

So it is possible to create elements for React component that are dynamic like this:

```
let myTag = myType === "header" ? 'th' : 'td';

React.createElement(
  myTag,
  {className: 'some-class'},
  <div className="some-class">some content</div>
)
```